# Changing a variable outside of a if statement using curses

Tags: python

This could be super simple but I can’t think of a solution. I want to be able to change a variable outside of a if statement.  I have this in a try loop.

For example:

Try:

```
X = 0

If char == ord (‘w’):
     X += 1
```

The only problem is that once it runs again the value of x will return to 0. How do I reassign the value of x to be the new number?

Comment: Save the number in a file and read it from there.

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax. *"I want to be able to change a variable outside of a if statement"*, you can, just use the assignment operator on it anywhere. Looks like you mean you want the value to persist after the execution of the program, in that case you need to save it somewhere and retrieve it.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: try without except and finally, capitalized keywords, wrong quotation marks. What is this?

Comment: Spencer Wieczorek can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

assign as an argument of the function what you want to change from one side and inside of the function make sure to use "return" the value that you want to be changed.
Once done push the same returned as an argument, with a loop most likely.

```
def function_name(x):
    x +=1
    print('New X Value',x)
    return x

for i in range(5):
    function_name(i)
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This solution suggestion is if the application only runs once. If the application is stopped and restarted, this won't work. The suggestion in the comment about storing to a file would be an ideal solution here.

Comment: I’d be running a try/finally loop so it would constantly be going.

Comment: That has a while true:

Comment: Still don’t have a solution.